# Fujitsu Scanning with Java

Tags: java

I am developing a java application to scan papers using Fujitsu 7260 , but am facing a problem which is the scanning user interface hangs when i press the scan button

My code is as following :

```
try {
Scanner scanner=null;
        scanner = Scanner.getDevice();
        devices=scanner.getDeviceNames();
        scanner.select(devices[1]);
        scanner.addListener((ScannerListener) this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

the scan button action :

```
try
    {
        scanner.acquire();
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        ex.getMessage();
    }
```

the method that handles the scan event :

```
public void update(ScannerIOMetadata.Type type, ScannerIOMetadata metadata) {
    startScan.setEnabled(true);


    if (type.equals(ScannerIOMetadata.ACQUIRED)) {
        BufferedImage SCimg = metadata.getImage();
        //ColorConvertOp op = new ColorConvertOp(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY), null);
        //op.filter(img, img);
        Image scaledInstance = SCimg.getScaledInstance(jLabel1.getWidth(), jLabel1.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(scaledInstance);
        jLabel1.setIcon(icon);

        scannedImagesList.add(SCimg);

        pages.setText(scannedImagesList.size()+"");
        currentPage.setText(scannedImagesList.size()+""); 

        if(!saveScanned.isEnabled())
            saveScanned.setEnabled(true);
        if(Integer.parseInt(pages.getText()) == Integer.parseInt(currentPage.getText()))
        {
            next.setEnabled(false);
            if(Integer.parseInt(pages.getText())==1)
            {
                next.setEnabled(false);
                prev.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else
                if(Integer.parseInt(pages.getText())> 1)
                {
                    prev.setEnabled(true); 
                }
        }
        startScan.setEnabled(true);
        try {
            new uk.co.mmscomputing.concurrent.Semaphore(0, true).tryAcquire(2000, null);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            IJ.error(e.getMessage());
            // e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else if (type.equals(ScannerIOMetadata.NEGOTIATE)) {
        ScannerDevice device = metadata.getDevice();
        try {
            device.setResolution(100);
            device.setShowUserInterface(false);
            device.setShowProgressBar(true);
        } catch (ScannerIOException e) {
            IJ.error(e.getMessage());
        }
         try{

         }
         catch(Exception ex){}
         /*
         * More options if necessary!
         * device.setShowProgressBar(true);
         * device.setRegionOfInterest(0,0,210.0,300.0);z
         * device.setResolution(
         100); }catch(Exception e){
         * e.printStackTrace(); }
         */
    } else if (type.equals(ScannerIOMetadata.STATECHANGE)) {

        // IJ.error(metadata.getStateStr());
    } else if (type.equals(ScannerIOMetadata.EXCEPTION)) {
        IJ.error(metadata.getException().toString());

    }

}
```

am using an open source library called : `mmscomputing`

what is the problem exactly ? and is there any open source library that can help me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't do this:  `} catch (Exception e) { }`.  You are squashing exceptions.

Comment: i did as you said, thanks for the motivation